# How to clone JsonObject (shadow and deep) following JSR-353 (JSON-P) spec

Tags: java, json, javax.json

I convert the JsonObject to String, then parsed them back.

```
public static JsonObject clone(JsonObject o) {
  if (o == null)
    return null;

  StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
  JsonWriter writer = Json.createWriter(buffer);
  writer.write(o);
  writer.close();

  return Json.createReader(new StringReader(buffer.toString())).readObject();
}
```

I look for more elegant method.

Comment: If disregarding that these objects are immutable, your question is a general Java question, how to clone an object in Java. Doesn't really have anything to do with JSON. One of the answers, by the way, is serialize it and then deserialize it, which is pretty much what you did here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no point cloning `JsonObject`. The [javadoc](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/json/JsonObject.html) states

> `JsonObject` class represents an **immutable** JSON object value (an
>   unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs).

Emphasis mine. Just re-use the object. No one will be able to change it.

Comment: What should one use if they want to clone and add an extra element inside it?

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat Good question. I can't find anything obvious. It seems like you have to build the new `JsonObject` from the properties of the old `JsonObject`. You have to go through the full process yourself.